# Call or get specific row data from ms sql to crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to call specific row from sql to crystal report? I want to get the customer data from ms sql and display it in the crystal report. I want to make it as a receipt of acknowledgement after filling up the form and ask the customer if he/she wants a copy of receipt or not. then the receipt will either send to email or print it as a pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, add a parameter to the report design and use that parameter in the record selection formula.